# how to find loop in a linked list based on data>

Tags: singly-linked-list

we can find the loop in a linked list keeping data intact, but is it possible to find a loop based on data.

if p1 and p2 are pointing to a list, pointers can be moved as followes
p1 = p1 -> next;
p2 = p2 -> next -> next;

if (p1 == p2)  then we can say that list  is in lopp.

My question is how to find loop  in a list based on data.

Comment: A linked list structure can only loop if it loops at the ends (Circular). Or do you mean if you have to pointers to nodes in linked lists (not necessary the same linked list) is there some way to check if you can reach a common element by traversing the lists? Or is it a graph structure you are traversing?

Comment: No. instead of finding the loop  in a list by traversing, is there a way to find loop based on the data that each node contains.

Comment: I still don't understand your question. Lists can only form a loop if they are are linked in one large cirle since they can only linked to next (and prev if need be). By moving a pointer like you do then you are traversing a list and you can't get "data" inside a linked list without traversing a linked list. Can you perhaps give a complete example.